# Instantiating class in member call

Tags: c++, oop

I have a member function defined as:

```
void printSomeData(std::ostream& str) const;
```

When I try to call that member from another class this way:

`myclass.printSomeData(std::ofstream("foo.txt"));`

I get the following errors:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘myclass::printSomeData(std::ofstream)’
>
> note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::ofstream {aka
>   std::basic_ofstream}’ to ‘std::ostream& {aka
>   std::basic_ostream&}’

However, if I call the function first instantiating the ofstream like below, I do not get any error, which I do not really understand:

```
std::ofstream foo("foo.txt");
myclass.printSomeData(foo);
```

Anyone can give me a clue?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference, which you are doing here:

```
myclass.printSomeData(std::ofstream("foo.txt"));
                            ^ temporary std::ostream object
```

When can do this instead:

```
std::ofstream os("foo.txt");
myclass.printSomeData(os);
```

you are passing a reference to an existing `std::ofstream` object, not a temporary.

You could also make `printSomeData` take a `const` reference, but presumably you want to change the stream in your function.

Answer (score 1):

```
void printSomeData(const std::ostream& str) const;
//                   |
//              notice const
```

Temporaries can't bind to non-`const` references, and `std::ofstream("foo.txt")` creates a temporary.

Or you can provide a non-temp to the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
void printSomeData(std::ostream& str) const;

myclass.printSomeData(std::ofstream("foo.txt"));
```

You try pass to function that take reference temporary-object (i.e. try to bind `rvalue` to `lvalue-reference`). It's incorrect. You can use `const std::ostream&`, but it's not good, also you can use `std::ostream&&` if you can use C++11.

```
void printSomeData(std::ostream&& str) const;
myclass.printSomeData(std::ofstream("foo.txt"));
```

But you cannot pass object of type ostream in this case.